# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Popper') "

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, babeljs

After adding `"@babel/transform-runtime"` plugin to `babel.rc` file
`popper.min.js` file throws this error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Popper') "
```

if I remove the plugin , it works fine

Comment: if I remove the plugin , it works fine.

Comment: Then remove it xD

Comment: removing the plugin gives error  "regeneratorruntime is not defined"

Comment: some more informations would be nice... what happens in the line, where the error occures?